How to link my stackexchange account to askubuntu?
My general stack exchange account is directly linked to SE, I'm not logging in via google or facebook or any of those. The associated email account is hosted on my personal domain.
I wanted to ask a question on https://askubuntu.com/ but my general account does not seem to be connected there (and contrary to various other SE sites I can't just join the site with my existing account) and the only login options provided are via google, facebook or Launchpad ( which seems to be an ubuntu specific account manager).
So how can I link my account to askubuntu? If I create a new account via google/ facebook that would necessarily have a different email address associated to it and would be a completely separated account.

Are you saying you don't see the Email and Password login on the Ask Ubuntu login page? Or that using that logon doesn't take you to your account there?

Your network account is already associated to Ask Ubuntu. When you visit Ask Ubuntu, do you see a Join this community button?

@HenryEcker I missinterpreted the screen you linked and thought this meant logging in via facebook. Putting in my email and pw there works as expected, thanks. Do you want to use your picture and write that as answer?
